# JSON parse error when using python requests for an API

Tags: python, json

If I run a curl statement in bash I get the result I want with no problem.

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Token ABC123' --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"enterprise/getEnterpriseEdges","params":{"with":["certificates","configuration","links","recentLinks","site","licenses","analyticsMode","selfHealing"],"edgeIds":[4723]},"id":34123423}' --request POST 'https://my-portal.velocloud.net/portal/'
```

When putting it into a python script, I keep getting this result instead of the massive JSON array of data.

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'error': {'code': -32603, 'message': 'JSON parse error'}, 'id': 1}
```

This is a copy of my Python script

```
import requests
payload_headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Token ABC123"
}
payload_data = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "enterprise/getEnterpriseEdges",
    "params": {
        "with": ["certificates", "configuration", "links", "recentLinks", "site", "licenses", "analyticsMode", "selfHealing"],
        "edgeIds": [4723]
    },
    "id": 34
}
response = requests.post("https://my-portal.velocloud.net/portal/", headers=payload_headers, data=payload_data, verify= False)
json_info = response.json()
print(json_info)
```

I was hoping to get a JSON output of the data like I get with the curl in bash, and eventually incorporate a loop to run through a list to get multiple JSONs to build out an API.

Comment: By the way, your `id` property is not the same in your payload

Comment: Since you're sending json, use `json=payload_data` instead of `data=payload_data`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I cannot thank you enough!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to dump the dict to str:

```py
import json

response = requests.post("https://my-portal.velocloud.net/portal/", 
                         headers=payload_headers,
                         data=json.dumps(payload_data),
                         verify=False)
```

Or just use `json` parameter:

```py
response = requests.post("https://my-portal.velocloud.net/portal/", 
                         headers=payload_headers,
                         json=payload_data,
                         verify=False)
```